# can't serialize access for this transaction in spring batch

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch with spring boot for process my Csv file. When i run the application i am getting below error trace.

```
2018-08-27 16:23:35.694  INFO 12016 --- [nio-9004-exec-1] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: ORACLE
2018-08-27 16:23:36.025  INFO 12016 --- [nio-9004-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2018-08-27 16:23:36.898  INFO 12016 --- [nio-9004-exec-1] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
2018-08-27 16:23:36.965  INFO 12016 --- [nio-9004-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
2018-08-27 16:23:37.005 ERROR 12016 --- [nio-9004-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotSerializeTransactionException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTI
```

After some search in google i find we have to instantiate **JobRepositoryFactoryBean**. so i did the same in my BatchConfiguration as below.

```
@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;   

 @Bean
        public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepository() throws SQLException{
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
            factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
            return factoryBean;

        }
```

And the **Datasource ** and **TransactionManager** beans are in my DBConfiguration as below.

```
@Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException
        {
            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser("xxxxxx");
            dataSource.setPassword("xxxxx");
            dataSource.setURL("xxxxx");
            dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);



            return dataSource;

        }

@Bean(name="transactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager  transactionManager() throws SQLException{

            DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(this.dataSource());
            return transactionManager;

        }
```

**Then i am getting below error**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field transactionManager in com.comcast.FileProcess.configuration.SprintgBatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'transactionManager' in 'DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' in your configuration.
```

Can any one help me to resolve this issues and to run my batch process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to the `APPLICATION FAILED TO START` error, you need to make your transaction manager bean definition method return the actual type `DataSourceTransactionManager` and not `PlatformTransactionManager`:

```
@Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager  transactionManager() throws SQLException{

        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(this.dataSource());
        return transactionManager;

    }
```

In regards to the `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction` error, it looks like the `IsolationLevelForCreate` is still `ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE` and your database is unable to serialize the transaction. This is probably due to your job repository which is not taken into account. I would make the `jobRepository` method return the job repository itself (as in the example [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#txConfigForJobRepository)) and not the factory bean:

```
@Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws SQLException{
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

This way, your job repository will be correctly configured with `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` and your database will not try to serialize transactions.

Comment: thanks for your time and for your inputs. I did the same what you suggested still getting below exceptions while launching application.

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
**************************
Field transactionManager in com.comcast.FileProcess.configuration.SprintgBatchConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'transactionManager' in 'DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'

Comment: Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager' in your configuration.

Comment: Is your `DBConfiguration` correctly placed in the package scanned by Spring Boot? It looks like beans defined there are not visible. So you need to make sure Spring boot scans this class and that is it correctly imported in your `com.comcast.FileProcess.configuration.SprintgBatchConfiguration`.

Comment: I have moved those code to Batch configuration and it fixed the issue. Thanks @Mahmoud for your time and help.

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine, I'm facing the same issue. But I'm using ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED. Will using `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` not create issue if two different jobs end up with same jobId?

Comment: It might! I just answered the question with the original isolation level of the OP (which is `ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED`). I personally recommend starting with `ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED` (which should prevent the case you mentioned), and then increase to `ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE` if needed.