# Spring Batch : How to change the default isolation level?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I read in the documentation :

> "The default is ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE, which prevents accidental
> concurrent execution of the SAME job"

However, when I launch DIFFERENT jobs at the the same time (with a default isolation level at SERIALIZABLE), I have the error : `ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction.` Is it normal ?

Second, to change the Default Isolation Level to READ_COMMITTED, I understood that we can't change this level in application.properties, and, that I have to redefine BatchConfigurer. Exact ?

Using BasicBatchConfigurer, I must define an explicit contructor (implicit super constructor BasicBatchConfigurer() is undefined for default constructor).
However, I have the error :

```
 Parameter 0 of constructor in MyBatchConfigurer required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties' that could not be found.
```

How to create : BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource and TransactionManagerCustomizers transactionManagerCustomizers ?

This is my code :

**PeopleApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class })
public class PeopleApplication {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =  new SpringApplicationBuilder(PeopleApplication.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) 
        .run(args);
        
        int exitValue = SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
        System.exit(exitValue);
    }
}
```

**MyBatchConfigurer.java**

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:fileA.properties")
public class MyBatchConfigurer extends BasicBatchConfigurer implements CommandLineRunner, ExitCodeGenerator {

    protected MyBatchConfigurer(BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource, TransactionManagerCustomizers transactionManagerCustomizers) {
         super(properties, dataSource, transactionManagerCustomizers);
     }
     
     @Override
     protected String determineIsolationLevel() {
            return "ISOLATION_" + Isolation.READ_COMMITTED;
     }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Regards.

---

**RESPONSE :**

---

use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` instead of :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Like this, the bean BatchProperties, DataSource and TransactionManagerCustomizers will be automatically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the reply from Mahmoud that explains very clearly

[can't serialize access for this transaction in spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046643/cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-in-spring-batch).

Example for the usage is below and override only isolation level

```
--application.properties

spring.application.name=SpringBatch

####### SPRING ##############

spring.main.banner-mode=off
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
spring.batch.job.enabled=false // Disable default if you want to control

########JDBC Datasource########
#connection timeout 10 min
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5 
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=100
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000 
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000 
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true 
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBoot-HikariCP
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ngecom.ae:1521:ngbilling
spring.datasource.username=ngbilling
springbatch.datasource.password=ngbilling

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsadapterApplication.class, args);
    }

}

// Your manual batch scheduler

 class BatchJobScheduler extends BasicBatchConfigurer {
        @Autowired
        private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationArguments args;
        @Autowired
        private Job myJob;
        protected BatchJobScheduler(BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource,
                TransactionManagerCustomizers transactionManagerCustomizers) {
            super(properties, dataSource, transactionManagerCustomizers);
        }
        @Override
        protected String determineIsolationLevel() {
            return "ISOLATION_" + Isolation.READ_COMMITTED;
        }
        //@Scheduled(cron = "${batch.cron}")
        public void notScheduledJob() {
                appId= args.getOptionValues("appId").get(0);
                JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("jobId"+appId, System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .toJobParameters();
                jobLauncher.run(myJob, params);
        }
       

// Your batch Configuration And Spring will do everything for you to available

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfiguration {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);
    
  
    @Value("${batch.commit.chunk}")
    private Integer chunkSize;

    @Value("${batch.error.skipCount}")
    private Integer skipErrorCount;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationArguments args;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; 

    @Bean
    public Job myJob() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(new JobListener()).start(myStep()).build();
    } 

   @Bean
    public Step myStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").<InputObject, OutPutObject>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(yourReader(null)).processor(yourProcessor()).writer(yourWriter())
                //.faultTolerant()
                //.skipLimit(skipErrorCount).skip(Exception.class)//.noSkip(FileNotFoundException.class)
                .listener(invoiceSkipListener())
                //.noRetry(Exception.class)
                //.noRollback(Exception.class)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: In the post that you mentioned, Mahmoud only explains to make a jobRepository() returning a JobRepository (and not a JobRepositoryFactoryBean). It doesn't answer to my question. It doesn't help me to know what I have to write in getTransactionManager(), getJobLauncher() and getJobExplorer().

Comment: Please find the sample snippet above as I can see you are not doing any customization on repository or transaction manager and let spring batch will handle this. Please share your code if not works.

Comment: Thank you, it's little bit clearer. However, how to create : BatchProperties properties, DataSource dataSource and TransactionManagerCustomizers transactionManagerCustomizers ? I've just updated my code in my question.

Comment: Added end to end sample code . Please resolve compilation issues as it may not be proper syntax. Properties, Data Source and Transaction managers are auto injected by spring/spring boot and you will always get handle to customize if you  want. Best example  is "Multiple data source configuration"

Comment: I understood my problem : the bean "BatchProperties" wasn' t found because I excluded BatchAutoConfiguration.class with : @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class })
I changed it to @EnableAutoConfiguration and it works.
Thank you very much for your help Rakesh.