# ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction - Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

On running multiple Spring batch jobs at same time, I am getting this error :

**Error : 8177, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 ), OriginalSql = INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?), Error Msg = ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:637) [ojdbc8-21.3.0.0.jar:21.3.0.0.0]
... 126 more**

On reading further I found one answer suggesting to set IsolationLevelForCreate to "ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED", link as follow

[can't serialize access for this transaction in spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046643/cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction-in-spring-batch)

However when I am trying to enable it through annotation, I am not able to find the property "isolationLevelForCreate" in the annotation EnableBatchProcessing

@EnableBatchProcessing(isolationLevelForCreate = "ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED").

I am referring to spring doc:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html

Code

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.my.example")

 @EnableBatchProcessing(isolationLevelForCreate = "ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED")// error here for the property

 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})

 @EnableJpaRepositories

 @Configuration

 @EnableScheduling

 @EnableCaching
```

---

Update after doing the code changes to create Job repository:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.my.example")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SessionAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching

public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }




    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        return args -> {
            logger.debug("Successfully Setup !!!");
            logger.debug(jobRegistry.getJobNames().toString());
            logger.info("Successfully Started the Application");
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
         
 //factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }


}
```

Tried the above code with ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED and ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE but got same error.
Checked that all classes are on the scan path also. Anything I am missing here for configuration.

Comment: isolationLevelForCreate attribute has been added recently in Spring Batch version 5.0.2. Consider updating you Spring Boot/Spring Batch.

Comment: BTW: I would rather use ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ instead of ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED

Comment: Thanks Mar-Z.  The Spring batch version 5 comes with the pre-requisite to have Java 17. Is there any alternative to resolve this without upgrading the Java version?

Comment: No, spring batch 5 requires java 17. The alternative is to override the isolation level for v4 as shown in the question/answer you shared.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I tried the suggestions but still facing the same error. Added the code snippet above, any issue with that?